# Get Drawable size of ImageView after scaling

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView in my layout. Its width and height are both set to fill_parent. The scaleType is set to fitCenter. I am in landscape mode. So if I have a square src image, when scaled up it will display me two borders, on the left and on the right, which perfectly suits me. But how can I get the dimensions of these borders ? The dimensions of the bitmap won't help for sure, and the dimensions of the ImageView are equal to the screen's.

I have asked for intrinsicwidth but it seems to give me the width of the drawable before it has scaled up.

I have tried adjustViewBounds but the ImageView still fills all the parent.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make a RectF to represent the original picture size, scale it with a matrix into a new RectF, then use this to find your dimensions.

Comment: How can I get the RectF representing the original size ? In fact I would avoid to call the bitmap if possible.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here [Get drawable displayed size after scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726004/get-drawable-displayed-size-after-scaling/27982481#27982481)
on how to calculate displayed size for FIT_CENTER scaleType.

And for the calculating the border dimensions just substract calculated value and divide by 2 from the imageView dimesnsions.